# Geometry Node, How to select easy creating patterns on Mesh Surface (ex. metal deposits)

Tags: geometry-nodes, selection-tools

Working out with rock containing different ressources deposits and try using geometry nodes for it (find base on youtube... not smart enough :)). Although looking for effect on rock surface not on extra mesh adding.
[image: Graphical node]

Result is useful, although selection faces afterwards is pain in ass. Is there any way of quick select this created pattern (instead of manually selecting each face)?
[image: effect after applying]

[image]

Comment: what also is a pain in the ass is that GN questions are asked without the blend file so we have to rebuild everything manually instead of just downloading and improving it....

Comment: Where is the problem @Chris? If no blend file is available, then the answer is just a little more generic ... or is only answered at some point (or not at all). Nobody forces you to do it. No offense. Thanks anyway for your commitment.

Comment: @NotSoEpicBlenderMaster In the future, please share your blend file from the beginning for questions regarding Geometry Nodes, and always use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your file. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: If you assign a material, you can then easily select by material (shift G)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply capture an attribute (boolean) of the cutter object, and then move just that selection, like so:

[image]

[image]

---- update

if you use the viewer node, you will see, that your faces have the wrong orientation:

[image]

so if you mute the flip faces node, it should work.

[image]

Comment: Thx, for answer, unfortunately not working. Dropped *.blend file above, can you try on it?

Comment: try muting the flip faces node. The viewer node is helpful for debugging. i updated my answer. Looks like boolean face is necessary in your case.

Comment: Thx, for answer @Chris, although  flip faces was set in order to achieve this edges intersecting  faces effect instead of adding depth to main rock... (check second picture) start thinking that maybe should try with projecting some noise based mesh on surface